Refresh ID token in Blazor Web Assembly using MSAL
I have a Blazor Web Assembly application which uses the Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal package. I'm authenticating through Azure and I get an ID token. To call my API I have to include this ID token in the HttpClient's message header (as a Bearer token). To achieve this I tried the BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler but it gets the Access Token instead of an ID token.
I checked the AuthenticationService.js and it has no wrapper for getting a new ID token silently if it is expired (only the getAccessToken function).
For getting the ID token from the browser storage is quiet simply but I need the ability to renew if expired.
Is there any solution for this?
